# Swift on iOS: Task on global queue adds 2nd task to main queue to display UIImageView, which does not display

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to display a UIImageView icon that moves across the screen.  But icon doesn't display.

1. viewDidLoad does this:
   DispatchQueue.global().async{   app_class.run_app()  }
2. run_app gets next XY location from array sim_locations_track_Array, converts to screen position, and does this to display the UIImageView icon:
   DispatchQueue.main.sync{ ... CGRect ... }

But nothing displays.

Here is my code...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var app_title: UILabel!

    static let wrist_band_UIImageView: UIImageView = {
       let theImageView = UIImageView()
       theImageView.image = UIImage( systemName: "applewatch" )
       theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //You need to call this property so the image is added to your view
       return theImageView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad()         
    {
        print("viewDidLoad...")
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview( ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView )

        DispatchQueue.global().async{ 
            app_class.run_app()
        }
    }
 }

 


 class app_class
 {
    // X, Y, Z, timestamp in seconds
    static let sim_locations_track_Array: [Int]  = [     0, 0, 0,   3,
                                                            0, 1, 0,   3,
                                                            0, 2, 0,   3,
                                                            0, 3, 0,   3,
                                                            0, 0, 0,   -999 ]

    static let items_per_time = 4

    
    static var screen_width = 100
    static var screen_height = 100
        static var screen_offset_x = 400
        static var screen_offset_y = 400
    static var screen_location_x = 0


    // Run app that animates track of user following sim locations track.
    static func run_app()
    {
            var xcoord = 0
            var ycoord = 0
            var delay_time_seconds = 1.0
            var locations_index = 0
            var map_multiplier = 10
            var loop = 0

        // Loop for each location:
            while true
            {
                //  Read XY from locations track:
                var board_x = sim_locations_track_Array[ locations_index * items_per_time ]
                var board_y = sim_locations_track_Array[ locations_index * items_per_time + 1 ]
                var relative_timestamp_seconds = sim_locations_track_Array[ locations_index * items_per_time + 3 ]
                    var screen_y = screen_height - board_x
                    var screen_x = screen_width / 2 + board_y

                // Not end of data?
                if  relative_timestamp_seconds > 0
                {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView.frame = CGRect(   x: screen_x * map_multiplier, 
                                                                                        y: screen_y * map_multiplier,
                                                                                        width: screen_width, 
                                                                                        height: screen_height)
                        }
                        sleep( UInt32( relative_timestamp_seconds ))
                    locations_index += 1
                }
                else          // End of locations track data?
                {
                    locations_index = 0
                }
            }
    }
}        // end of app_class
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `sync` on the `main` thread this leads to deadlock, use `async` instead.

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync{
             ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView.frame = CGRect(   x: screen_x * map_multiplier, 
                                                                                        y: screen_y * map_multiplier,
                                                                                        width: screen_width, 
                                                                                        height: screen_height)
}
```

`sync` will dispatch work to another queue but the current queue will wait till work is finished. In simple words, sync blocks the current queue. [sync(execute:) doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync)

Comment: Welcome to StackO, Bogdan!  I hope it'll be as beneficial to you as for me, these past 10 years.   Changed to .async but it still doesn't display.

Comment: @DougNull In my case, deleting the `theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` line helped

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't actually do anything. You're using a static method on your `app_class` class, which then fetches a static **computed** property (`wrist_band_UIImageView`) of the ViewController class, updates the frame of that newly created computed UIImageView, and then... drops the image view on the floor.

The result of getting a value from `ViewController.wrist_band_UIImageView` is a newly created `UIImageView` that is not part of any view hierarchy. Unless you install it into a view hierarchy somewhere, it won't do anything.

Another thing. This code:

```
DispatchQueue.global().sync() {
    sleep( UInt32( relative_timestamp_seconds ))
}
```

Makes no sense. You're running it from a background thread. Then you invoke another background queue and tell it to synchrnously... go to sleep, for some potentially large number of seconds. What is the point of that? If you want the current background job to sleep, just invoke sleep directly. Dispatching a call to a global sync queue that you just tell to sleep is absurd.

You should take a step back and explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try making your `wrist_band_UIImageView` a lazy var of the view controller. It will get created the first time you reference it, and then when your background queue code references it, it will reference the same object. Better yet, give your background queue a closure that takes a CGRect as a parameter, and have the closure update the view's frame.

Comment: As rule, you should not have objects mess around with other object's views. You should provide some clean interface that enables the other object to say "here is a new value. Do what you will with it."

Comment: Agreed.  task not needed for sleep(1).